# remove letters from a data extraction leaving only numbers Python

Tags: python, string, selenium

I have this selenium code

```
x = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paginacaoSuperior"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/h2/span').text
```

this code returns this value to me

```
result 1 to 299
```

I wanted to remove these values

```
result 1 to
```

leaving only `299`

with this value `299` divide by `12`

```
    y = 'Result1to'
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x = x.replace(y[i],"")
    print(x)
```

I used this code but gave error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following to sove the issue:

```
s = "result 1 to 299"
print(round(int(s.split()[-1])/12, 4))

# first action is s.split() we devide string and get list
# s.split()[-1] take the last element of the list
# int(s.split()[-1]) convert it to integer (you can use float instead)
# round(int(s.split()[-1])/12, 4) divide by 12 and show only 4 digits after point
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split` with negative index.

**Ex:**

```
s = "result 1 to 299"
print(s.split()[-1]) # -->299
```